# Display Message in MDI Parent Status Bar from Child c#

Tags: c#, winforms, statusbar

This is simplest possible thing, but I cant update text on status bar. I just started working in c# but cannot find solution. I tried below code:

**Mdiparent**

```
public void StutasText(string text)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = text;
}
```

**Child form**

```
 MDIParent1 obj = new MDIParent1();
 obj.StutasText("Hello world");
 obj.Refresh();
```

Its not showing status text in the status bar.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In the MDI Parent form, I assume you have toolStripStatusLabel1. If you dont have, you can add this by clicking on the little black arrow in the menuStrip control.

**Option 1**

In your MDI Parent (let's assume, frmMain is the MDI Parent form) form where you have the StatusStrip, goto frmMain.Designer.cs file and find the place

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;
```

make this,

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;
```

Then from your child pages you can access like below.

```
ToolStripStatusLabel statusStrip=((frmMain)(frmMdiChild.MdiParent)).toolStripStatusLabel1
```

**Option 2**

Declare a public property which will return the toolStripStatusLabel1 control or method where you can set the text property of the toolStripStatusLabel1 in the MDI Parent form. If you return the menuStrip1 itself then you have access to all the properties of that control. If you declare a method, which will set the text property of the toolStripStatusLabel1 then you can only set the text. Decide on what you want, based upon your requirement.

An implementation which returns the menuStrip1 control.

```
 public ToolStripStatusLabel GetStatusBar
 {
  get
   {
     return this.toolStripStatusLabel1;
   }
 }
```

then from your child pages, you can use,

```
ToolStripStatusLabel statusStrip=((frmMain)(frmMdiChild.MdiParent)).GetStatusBar;
```

**Option 3**

To make it little bit more prettier, you can declare a method in a common class. Then you can reuse this in other child forms.

```
 public void ShowStatusbarMessage(Form frmMdiChild, string message, NotifierType notificationType)
   {
       ToolStripStatusLabel statusStrip=((frmMain)(frmMdiChild.MdiParent)).GetStatusBar;
       statusStrip.Text = message;
       if (notificationType == NotifierType.SuccessInfo)
       {
           statusStrip.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
       }
       else if (notificationType == NotifierType.Warning)
       {
           statusStrip.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
       }
       else
       {
           statusStrip.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

       }

   }
```

Here, NotifierType is an enum

Answer (score 2):

```
((mdiMain)MdiParent).toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "My Text";
//but you must change the modifier property of toolStripStatusLabel to public etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new instance of MDIParent1, not using the instance that is shown/the instance your child form belongs to.

You could try using

```
this.MdiParent
```

instead of

```
new MDIParent1()
```

Comment: What kind of error? Did you downcast this.MdiParent to MDIParent1?

Comment: can you give coding for that ?

Answer (score 1):

((frmMDI)this.MdiParent).yourcontrol.yourproperty=yourvalue;
frmMDI is unique name of MDI form.

Answer (score 1):

**First**
In "mdi parent name".Designer.cs, change the type or member *private* to *public*

**Second** In your code add the next code 
`(("mdi parent name")MdiParent).toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "your text";`